# How to swap items from two recyclerview items that are in two fragments in one activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two fragments (a and b) inside an `Activity` according to the picture below.

I am able to delete from first one but how to add that item to favorites fragment `RecyclerView`?

**Deleting actress name and adding to favorites**

[image: deleting actress name and adding to favorites]

```
My Viewholder code for RecyclerView Fragment one class:
addToFavoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mArrayList.remove(getAdapterPosition());

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

How to add this deleted item inside adapter of Favorites `Recyclerview`?

Comment: Did you try the solutions provided on the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method inside your adapter that removes an item from the `RecyclerView`, and returns the given item.

Then, you can use this item reference to add it to the second `RecyclerView`.

**Pseudocode example**

```
public myItem removeAndGetItem(int position) {
    myItem item = mArrayList.get(position);
    mArrayList.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return item;
}
```

Then you could call something like (also, pseudocode):

```
myItem item = adapter1.removeAndGetItem(position);
adapter2.add(item);
```

Adjust the examples to your code, and it should do the trick.

**Edit**

I misread the part about the RecyclerViews being on different Fragments.
So, you can still do what I said on the example above, you'll just have to pass that item to the second Fragment, using [Fragment callbacks](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), or [Broadcasting the item](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), or even through an [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Instead of using `notifyDataSetChanged()` which can be very costly, try to use [`notifyItemRemoved(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRemoved(int)) instead. As you can see on [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html):

> If you are writing an adapter **it will always be more efficient to use the more specific change events if you can**. Rely on notifyDataSetChanged() as a last resort.

Comment: oh..yes many thanks i used callback from the first fragment and it worked..many thanks @Mauker

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is maintain a list of actresses (either locally or on the server) with each one containing an `isFavorite` boolean attribute.

Then, while you have one global list, each recyclerview is only showing a subset:

- On the left, you show all actresses where `isFavorite` is set to false.
- On the right, you show all actresses where `isFavorite` is set to true.

How you update it could be done a few different ways, but here is what I recommend at a high level:

Have an onClick listener for each one that bubbles up to the activity, so the activity is aware any time an actresses's favorite state changes. Every time the state changes for an actress, tell your adapters in each fragment to update.

If you don't want to refresh the entire list every time, you could integrate a `remove` and `add` method like [Mauker's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46832473/3131147).